# Linear regression as $\dim(\beta) \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, statistics, regression

Consider the linear regression,
$$
Y_i = X_i\beta + U_i \qquad E[X_i'U_i]=0
$$
where $X_i=(1,W_{i},W_{i}^2,..\ldots,W_i^K)$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{K+1}$. The joint distribution of $(X_i,Y_i)$ is given and $\beta$ is unknown. Then,
$$
\beta =(E[X_i'X_i])^{-1}E[X_i'Y_i]
$$
I am wondering what can be said about $\beta$ as $K \rightarrow \infty$ i.e. the dimension of $\beta$ approaches infinity? Specifically, is $\beta$ unique?  Can $\beta$ be expressed in terms of functionals of the joint distribution of $(X_i,Y_i)$? Is there a way to estimate $\beta_k$ for each $k$? etc.

Comment: Normally when discussing what happens if some parameter runs of to infinity there is some implicit assumption along the lines of 'while all other parameters stay fixed'. Here it is not clear to me what that would be: as K grows bigger we have to come up with more and more $W$ss so you should make some statement about where they come from before you can answer the question. (Like 'the $W$s are idd from some distribution', but that would be orthogonal to how you think about the $W$s in most practical applications)

Comment: I'll need to rethink about the question. What I had in mind was something like a Taylor expansion of the function $g(\cdot)$ in the equation $Y_i=g(X_i)+U_i$ and $E[U_i|X_i]=0$ but I haven't expressed this clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If your sample size remains constant, you will have $k>n$ where $i=1,...,n$ so your matrix will not be invertible and an infinite (continuum) betas will be able to minimize the square errors.

Comment: I'm actually thinking in terms of the population so sample size can even be removed i.e. $Y=X\beta +U$ and $E[U|X]=0$ where the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is given and $\beta$ unknown... but I don't think I've expressed my question very well. I'm trying to get at something like a Taylor expansion of $Y=g(X) +U$ but need to rethink what exactly I mean. thanks.

Comment: You need a sample size to be able to write $(E[X_i'X_i])$.  Without it, the expression for beta in the question doesnt make sense.

Comment: I don't think I need a sample because I know the population i.e. $Y=X\beta+U$ and $E[X'U]=0$ so $E[X'Y]=E[X'X]\beta+E[X'U]$, inverting $\beta=(E[X'X])^{-1}E[X'Y]$.... to estimate $\beta$ then I'd use a sample $\widehat \beta = [\sum X_i X_i']^{-1}[\sum X_i Y_i]$.

Comment: How do you know you can invert $E[X X^\prime]$? What is the dimension of the matrix $E[X X^\prime]$? What is the dimension of the vector $X$? What happens if the dimension of $X$ is lower than  k?

Comment: $E[X'X]$ has dimension $K \times K$. $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^K$ is a draw from $X \in \mathbb{R}^K$... sometimes the notation is $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ but not here.

Comment: Just 2 points: 1) So both the dimension of X and Y are increasing with k, so maybe you should write $X^k$, $Y^k$ and  $U^k$ since their joint distribution depends on k. 2) Maybe your question should be about regression in an infinite dimensional space. Consider X a random vector in $\ell^2$, beta a point  in $\ell^2$, etc